# Keycloak using Ionic with Capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, keycloak, capacitor

I want to create an android app using keycloak with ionic (angular) and capacitor. Everything works fine in the web browser but when I want to run my app in an android emulator I get a white screen. Perhaps the reason for it is that I initialize keycloak at the start and capacitor can't access keycloak?

I've found out that there's a way to create a custom [keycloak adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#custom-adapters) but I have no idea how implement it...

Plus, there's another [keycloak-ionic](https://github.com/JohannesBauer97/keycloak-ionic) dependency. Maybe someone has tried it out? But I don't know which approach is the best:

**app.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
    },
    CookieService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**keycloak-init.factory.ts:**

```
export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: environment.keycloakApi,
        realm: 'quarkus',
        clientId: 'quarkus-app',
      },
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer',
      initOptions: {
          onLoad: 'check-sso',
          silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
              window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      },
    });
}
```

At the moment I am using:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
    "keycloak-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^19.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^14.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

I open my app in android studio with this command:

```
ionic cap run android -l --external --target=Pixel_3_API_30 --host=<ip_adress> --port=8100  --public-host=<ip_adress> --open
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid ID 0x00000000.
```

And these warnings:

```
node_modules\keycloak-js\dist\keycloak.mjs depends on 'base64-js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
    For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

node_modules\keycloak-js\dist\keycloak.mjs depends on 'js-sha256'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
    For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

Comment: may i know your ionic framework version?

Comment: Sure, "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9". I've edited my post with my dependencies.

Comment: what errors do you get from adb logcat?

Comment: I just get these errors:
Invalid ID 0x00000000.

And these warnings:
node_modules\keycloak-js\dist\keycloak.mjs depends on 'base64-js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts. For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


I start my app with: 

ionic cap run android -l --external --target=Pixel_3_API_30 --host=192.168.178.20 --port=8100  --public-host=192.168.178.20 --open 

When I open http://192.168.178.20:8100 in my browser it just works.